# Rescale image and rotate image with only numpy array manipulation

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I would like to rescale and rotate image which I transform to numpy array with Pillow library (Image.open(..))
But i can use only numpy array manipulation.
Any tip or article how to do that? Without use of cv etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIL to resize and rotate like this

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('Your/image/path')
img_120 = img.rotate(120)
img_re = img.resize((width, hight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Comment: Anyone can help me somehow?